# WooCommerce Checkout fields settings and customization hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

does anyone know where the original checkout field settings are, within the Woocommerce plugin files? E.g The original field labels and placeholders etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is **no Checkout fields settings** in Woocommerce…
>
> But you **can customize them** using: 
>   - [The Woocommerce Developer Documentation reference to customize checkout fields](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) 
>   - or [any of the availaible plugins](https://www.google.fr/search?q=woocommerce%20checkout%20plugins) which most of them are commercial.

**1) Checkout fields are managed essentially by 3 Woocommerce classes:** 
- [`WC_Checkout`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Checkout.html) Class using [`get_checkout_fields()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#186-232) *(and [`get_value()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#1013-1039) method)* 
- [`WC_Countries`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Countries.html) Class using [`get_default_address_fields()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#610-689) and [`get_address_fields()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#1168-1226) 
- *[`WC_Customer`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html) Class used also for My account Address fields.*

And uses [`woocommerce_form_field()` template function](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2066-2278) where the different field types are defined.

**2) The main hooks involved in customizations are:** 
- [`woocommerce_default_address_fields`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#707) filter hook and [StackOverFlow related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_default_address_fields)
- [`woocommerce_checkout_fields`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#225) filter hook  and [StackOverFlow related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_checkout_fields)
- [`woocommerce_billing_fields`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#1225) filter hook  and [StackOverFlow related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_billing_fields)
- [`woocommerce_shipping_fields`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Countries.html#1225) filter hook  and [StackOverFlow related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_shipping_fields)
- [`woocommerce_form_field_{$args\[type\]}`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2271) filter hook  and [StackOverFlow related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_form_field_)

**3) The main related templates involved** [that can be overridden through via the theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) are: 
- `checkout/form-checkout.php` 
- `checkout/form-billing.php` 
- `checkout/form-shipping.php` 
- `checkout/form-loging.php`

**Related:** [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 3):

```
For Original Fields please visit on your "woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-billing.php"

Here you will see a function
//This below line of code is responsible to get the fields
$fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' );

//this below code is resposnible to echo those fields/labels etc
woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );

If you want to go in depth please visit woocommerce/includes/wc-template-fucntions.php "function woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null )", check this.
```

Hope this may help you out!