# Hide custom checkout fields from appearing in WooCommerce my account edit address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, account

I've created a woo-commerce checkout field  with wooocmmerec checkout field editor plugin like the below image [image] that is supposed to appear conditionally at the checkout and here is the code that enables it .

```
function ga_checkout_fields($fields) {
    global $user_country;
    //$user_country = 'in'; //for test in dev

    if( $user_country != 'in')  { //hide gst if the location is not india
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_gst_number']);
    }
    
    if( $user_country != 'br')  { //hide taxid if the location is not brazil
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_br_tax_id']);
    }

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ga_checkout_fields' );
```

This code works flawlessly at the checkout but the problem is when a user tries to edit their billing address at my account then they see those custom fields and are not able to edit their address. I don't want to display nor save the custom fields at all to the customers at their my account edit billing address form.
I tried the below code to unset those custom fields at the billing address in my account, I am able to hide the fields but am not able to save them as the tax id field is required at the checkout. I want the tax id to be required at the checkout and I don't want to have any custom fields at the edit billing address in my account? Any insights on how to achieve that?

```
function ga_remove_the_address_field( $address, $load_address ) {//this removes fields in the edit form
    global $user_country;
 
    if( $user_country != 'in')  { //hide gst if the location is not india
        unset($address['billing_gst_number']);
    }
    
    if( $user_country != 'br')  { //hide taxid if the location is not brazil
        unset($address['billing_br_tax_id']);
    }

    return $address;

}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_address_to_edit', 'ga_remove_the_address_field', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide custom fields from my account > Edit billing address, you will use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'ga_remove_account_custom_fields', 1000 );
function ga_remove_account_custom_fields( $fields ) {
    // Only on My account > Edit address section
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-address') ) {
        // Here define the custom field Ids to hide in the array
        $field_ids = array('billing_gst_number', 'billing_br_tax_id');

        foreach ( $field_ids as $field_id ) {
            if( isset($fields[$field_id]) ) {
                unset($fields[$field_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Note:** For shipping fields you will use the hook `woocommerce_shipping_fields` instead.

---

Related:

- [Customize addresses fields on WooCommerce My account and Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729859/customize-addresses-fields-on-woocommerce-my-account-and-checkout/57730215#57730215)
- [WooCommerce Checkout fields settings and customization hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421397/woocommerce-checkout-fields-settings-and-customization-hooks/54425615#54425615)

Comment: @YeshDev I have updated the answer code. Is not necessary to remove question acceptance next time, just a comment with the related issue is enough (you can remove acceptance when author doesn't solve the issue after some time)…